# Why can't I drop primary key? "See previous errors" but no previous error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to remove a clustered primary key (so I can rebuild it differently) like this:

```
alter table Title.Parcel drop constraint PK_Parcel
```

This runs indefinitely.  As soon as I cancel, it says:

```
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

But there is no "previous error".

I have run `sp_help` to establish that there are no foreign keys referencing this primary key.  What else should I be looking for?

I suppose the answer to this question could potentially also be an answer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350749/is-there-a-way-to-actually-see-previous-errors-since-there-are-none-visible-i).

Comment: Is it a clustered primary key?

Comment: If your PK is clustered, dropping it will lead to turning your table from clustered index to heap. It can take quite a while for large tables, especially if they have other indices.

Comment: For OP, that is because previously, if there was a clustered index, all non-clustered indexes map to the clustering key. If you drop the clustered index, then all of those indexes must be rebuilt to point to the RID of the row instead.

Comment: In other words.... try dropping all non clustered indexes first. In future if you have long running queries use something like `sp_Whoisactive` to see whats going on behind the covers. For example you might see that it is busy rebuilding a non clustered index.

Comment: @Pittseburgh DBA, yes it is - question edited accordingly. (Thanks for all your interesting comments)

Comment: So it's just a matter of time to do all the associated work. Presumably then the query would complete without errors if I just waited long enough, and then the error would not be thrown?

Comment: How are you executing the ALTER TABLE? With SSMS or with another tool?

Comment: @RazvanSocol - with SSMS